# How to set chinese analyzer to a field in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there an example how to set chinese language analyzer for certain field in Elasticsearch?

Documents contain fields with both english and chinese languages and I would like to configure analyzer for one certain field.

Comment: refer   http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#chinese-analyzer

Comment: If you can share your current mappings, sample data and queries it will be far easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try https://github.com/medcl/elasticsearch-analysis-ik.

Here are some documents in Chinese:

- http://www.nosqldb.cn/1368777631032.html
- http://my.oschina.net/xiaohui249/blog/232784

Basically, You just need to install the ik-analyzer-plugin and the dictionaries(by simply copying files), enable it in elasticsearch.yml, and then set the analyzer to the field you want to use it.